# Align 2 different elements in bootstrap center-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my code:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="center-block" style="width:700px">
      <h2 class="text-center lead" style="font-size:25px; font-family:Verdana;">"He changed the way each one of us see the world"</h2>
      <p class="text-center" style="font-size:15px; font-family:Verdana; color:grey"><i>- President Barack Obama</i></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to obtain the following output with my text :

[image]

But how do I make "-President Barack Obama" align with its preceding text like "-Indian Prime Minister Manmohan Singh" in the image?

Comment: just don't align the text center?

Comment: Just remove `text-center` classes.

Comment: isnt there a way to do with text-center classes aswell?

Comment: @kartikeykant18 Why you use a class that centers the text but you don't want it centered? o_o

Comment: Why you need `text-center` class if you wants left aligned text?

Comment: i want both the elements to be centered but both to be aligned with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `class="text-left"` and `margin-left:25px"`

```
<p class="text-left" style="font-size:15px; font-family:Verdana; color:grey;margin-left:25px"><i>- President Barack Obama</i></p>
```

Comment: how did you find the margin?

Comment: is it kind of trail and error for different values? sorry but i am new to front end

Comment: yeah .if you change one of your style  then you need to change it with your script.